# Can't find test application with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, android-testing, robolectric

Using Robolectric 3.3.1. Having issues setting the application to my custom test application.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23, application = UnitTestApplication.class)
public class SomeTest {
////
}
```

I'm getting the exception below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find a class for package: null and class name: UnitTestApplication
at org.robolectric.DefaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(DefaultTestLifecycle.java:42)
    at org.robolectric.DefaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(DefaultTestLifecycle.java:12)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:103)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:289)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:203)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:109)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not find a class for package: null and class name: UnitTestApplication
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.ClassNameResolver.resolve(ClassNameResolver.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.DefaultTestLifecycle.createApplication(DefaultTestLifecycle.java:40)
    ... 23 more
```

The test runs just fine if I use the default application but I need a test implementation to configure my tests. What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: Do yo have UnitTestApplication class?

Comment: Yes i do, it's in the test package with the test